# Saving what I wrote on a Canvas in the Application Settings

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, appsettings

I am building a Windows Store Application that acts like a notebook. Every page has a Canvas, the pages are marked with an Index. I thought of saving a class (when exiting the page) containing: 
- a string about the Index of the page
- a IEnumerable of type , Children of the Canvas

I want to save this class locally in the app settings to be able to review what I wrote even after exiting my Application.

Is this possible? or I should serialize it as an Xml file to save it as a Collection in the Application Settings?

Comment: If I understand the scenerio you're explaining correctly.. Your question seems to regard persisting data locally using App Data. the data in question seems to be of a class type that is populated with control state(s): in a heirachrial structure. If you're going to persist control states and heirachrial structure between sessions then, yeah, you'll serialize your class and store it in the app settings.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

Comment: instead of serializing my class and store it in the app settings, can I save in an Isolate Storage like [here](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/)  and still have the same result?